# Python XLWT Foreign Key values

Tags: python, django, excel, foreign-key-relationship, xlwt

I am exporting database field to Excel file, everything works fine but my foreign key field is being printed as foreign key ID and not the actual value.

How can I fix it?

here is my code:

```
    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf8')
    sheet = book.add_sheet('Expense summary', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
    header_style = xlwt.easyxf('font:height 280, color blue, bold 1; border: bottom thick;')
    sum_style = xlwt.easyxf('font:height 200, color green, bold 1; border: top thick;')
    date_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    date_style.num_format_str = 'DD-MM-YYYY'
    currency_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    currency_style.num_format_str = '#,##0.00'
    xls_values = expense.filter(
                                user=request.user.id).values_list('date', 'amount', 'towho', 'forwhat', 'category', 'payment_method')
    headers = (ugettext("Date"), ugettext("Amount"), ugettext("To who"), ugettext("For what"), ugettext("Category"), ugettext("Payment method"))
    for i, header in enumerate(headers):
        col_width = 256 * 20
        sheet.col(i).width = col_width
        sheet.row(0).write(i, header, header_style)
    for row, rowdata in enumerate(xls_values):
        for col, val in enumerate(rowdata):
            if col == 0:
                sheet.write(row + 1, col, val, date_style)
            else:
                if col == 1:
                    sheet.write(row + 1, col, val, currency_style)
                else:
                    sheet.write(row + 1, col, val)
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=sample.xls'
    book.save(response)
    return response
```

the category field returns the ID number instead of the value.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: show your code - how are you exporting to excel? What have already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of enumerating `rowdata`, generate the row field by field:

```
for row, o in enumerate(xls_values):
    sheet.write(row + 1, 0, o.my_first_field, date_style)
    sheet.write(row + 1, 1, o.my_second_field, val, currency_style)
    sheet.write(row + 1, 2, o.my_category_field.name, val) # assuming name is what you want
```